# Blueprism web automation using excel

Tags: excel, blueprism

I want to fill a registration form by fetching data from excel using blueprism. In registration form the form redirects to another page after submission. But I am not able to do this flow in Process studio.

I Launched the Url and gave Loop start. The first data in excel is submitted but while fetching the second data from excel it throws an error message displaying

> Application already launched

This is the Url "http://nancysara.wufoo.com/forms/z1c5ojru1qfibiq"

Answer (score 0):

This error message happens when you are trying to use the Attach stage on an object that is already attached. You should have a logic in your object that checks whether attaching is necessary. Something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when trying to attach the Application or Browser that is being already attached to the Blueprism Object.

You can use "Read stage" to check the Application is connected or not.

Code looks like [Code Block to check application connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8yCH.png)

And read stage will be as below,

[Read Block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c83qt.png)

You can create this code in new page and call this page before doing any interaction with the application